# Parameters to factory method in C

Tags: c, parameter-passing, factory

I need to create an instance of my abstract data type, but creating the instance needs some parameters. Now, how should I pass these parameters to the function? There's a lot of parameters, and I would love to have most of them the default value. I see several ways to solve this, however I can not decide which is best.

#### First option:

`MyADT_t *my_adt_create( const char* a_long_config_string);`

..where `a_long_config_string` is a string like `"param1=value;param2=value"`

This is appealing, but I guess there will be a messy parsing of the string (and error checking) inside the function.

#### Second option:

`MyADT_t *my_adt_create( int paramc, char *paramv[]);`

This mimics the command line input style `main(int argc, char *argv[])` and could may be implemented with an command line option library, like getopt or popt.

#### Third option:

Use an variadic function like:
`MyADT_t *my_adt_create( int mandatory_param, ...);`

..and then in the function read the parameters in pairs of parameter and value. Maybe not much different from second option, but still different.

*Additional info:* I guess some of the parameters for the factory method will be provided from the command line options. Does this make the choice any simpler?

**Edit**
To clearify: What if I want my program to launch like this:
`myprog --some-general-opt=hello --adt-optinon-a=value --adt-option-b=value`
or maybe:
`myprog --some-general-opt=hello --adt-options='a_long_config_string'`

Comment: hmm i cant really suggest you the "right" method, but i would avoid the ellipsis method :P. I would take the second option just because it sounds most simple to use for me.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: use a `struct`. Pop it in an `.h` file somewhere, and pass that to the method: that way, you get type-safety, and it's totally obvious to the calling function what's going on.

Example of your struct `typedef` (uncompiled):

```
   typedef struct {
      int  size;
      char content_flags;
      ...
   } ADT_PARAMS;
```

Then, in your `ADT.c` file:

```
MyADT_t *my_adt_create(ADT_PARAMS *p) {
    ...
}
```

To handle the arguments coming in off the command line, there is a `getargs` function which solves the problem of getting named arguments generally, I personally prefer to knock something up with `sscanf`, so something like

```
const char *fmt = "--%s=%s";
int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    int i;
    const ADT_PARAMS p = {..default ADT parameters}
    for(i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
       char *key, *value;
       char *cur = *(argv + i);
       if(!sscanf(fmt, &key, &value)) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error reading argument: '%s'\n", cur);
           return 1;
       }
       if(!strcmp(key,"some-value")) {
           p.some-value = ...
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this, but this just wraps up the parameters in a structure. I then will face the same problem when creating `ADT_PARAM` structure from say, command line option parser. Maybe my original question was not clear enough. What if I wan my program to launch like this:  
`myprog --some-general-opt=hello --adt-optinon-a=value --adt-option-b=value`  
or maybe:  
`myprog --some-general-opt=hello --adt-options='a_long_config_string'`

Comment: Ah yes, OK: this is a `getargs` scenario (personally, I hate `getargs`). Here's what I'd recommend:

Comment: @RichardTownsend That comment is almost a [Fermat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem#Fermat.27s_conjecture)! :)